# Will there be license issue if I clone official docker node image and host it in private repo?

Tags: docker

We use https://hub.docker.com/_/node to build our apps in our private organisation. Due to rate limit of free usage, we are getting "Too many requests" error while pulling images from docker-hub.

We want to clone this image and host it in our own internal private docker repo. As an organisation, are we going to face any license issue if clone & host in our repo ? Only our organization uses this image to build our own product, we are not re-selling/ re-distributing to some one else.

Comment: What license or licenses is the code you are proposing copying under?

Comment: @PhilipKendall If I understand your question correctly, we're copying everything from node image which uses lot of other libraries. These libraries have their own licenses. As per https://github.com/docker-library/official-images, node image I mentioned is under Apache 2.0

Comment: In which case, you must enumerate and obey every license that is included. That's not something we can help you with.

Comment: I agree broadly with @PhilipKendall but will add that for free and open source licenses (i.e., that are listed as approved on the FSF's and OSI's websites), you can know with certainty that they allow you to host the image as you like, without inspecting all the particular terms of each license. If you can verify that each license used is a free and/or open-source license then you're good to go (but this may still be a nontrivial task).